# Plotting in MATLAB and legend

Tags: matlab, legend

Firstly, I'm trying to figure out a much more complicated situation, but this is the most minimal example I can provide. Suppose I want to present in a common figure the graphs of the 3 functions `sinx, sin(2x), sin(3x)` including their legends.

I can draw the graphs in a common figure, but I have trouble with `legend.` I provide you my algorithm (sorry for not being an optimized one, but I 'm not much in writing algorithms).

```
x = 0:0.01:2*pi;
for i = 1:3
    g = plot(sin(i*x));
    legend(sprintf('sin(%f *x)', i))
    hold on
end
hold off
g
```

Ιt would be great if you could help me fix my algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `DisplayName` to the `plot` function

```
x = 0:0.01:2*pi;
for i = 1:3
    g = plot(sin(i*x),'DisplayName',sprintf('sin(%.0f *x)', i));
    hold on
end
hold off
legend('Show','Location','NorthEast')
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. I didn't know about the `'DisplayName'` property

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be done without loops:

- Use [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to compute the product of each `i` times the vector `x`, and then compute the `sin` of that. This gives you a matrix, `s`. Build the matrix so that each `i` s a different *column*.
- Simply issue `plot(s)`. When you pass a matrix to [`plot`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html), a graph of each *column* is generated.
- Build a cell array containing the strings (you can use [`arrayfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) for that) and use that as the input argument to [`legend`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html).

Code:

```
x = 0:0.01:2*pi;
ii = 1:3;
s = sin(bsxfun(@times, ii, x.'));
plot(s)
str = arrayfun(@(k) ['sin(' num2str(k) '*x)'], ii, 'uniformoutput', false);
legend(str)
```

Result:

[image]